# error TS2416 Type 'Observable<APIResponse>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular8

I have an `Angular 8` app. This is how a service looks like:-

```js
export class UserService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public AddUser(user: User): Observable<APIResponse> {
    return this.http.post<APIResponse>(
      API.User + "register", 
      user //data
    ).pipe();
  }
}
```

But this is throwing the below error.

> error TS2416 `Type 'Observable<APIResponse>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'.`

But if I make the return type of the service same as input param type i.e., `Observable<User>` . Then no error.

In the app, every service would have diffent data type (input) but every service is going to have the APIResponse as return type.

**What is causing this error? How can I get rid of it?**

Thanks!

Comment: are you getting this error while using `AddUSer` method? and what you'r returning in pipe

Comment: Are you transforming the APIResponse to `User` type in `pipe`?

Comment: @jitender no while compilation itself

Comment: That won't fix your problem but if you don't put anything in pipe you can get rid of it.

Comment: Seems your API is sending your Observable of `User` type as response. Should you  convert the data type to `APIResponse` in your pipe? Kindly check if you are missing this

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, most likely that at some point in your app you are using this addUser(...) method, and there it is expected to return Observable. ApiResponse and User apparently have different structure.

You say all the services are returning the same ApiResponse type - is the data absolutely the same there? Or is there still some difference depending on the service input type? If the latter is the case (and I believe it is, since you must be fetching data as well), you should check typescript generics, it might be of great help to you: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: is the data absolutely the same there? Yes. the structure of the data would remain the same

Comment: In that case you should find the place where Observable<APIResponse> meets Observable<User> and see what went wrong there.